# Using tf.py_func() as a reader on queues gives out of range errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create an input pipeline using tf.py_func() as a reader on queues. My data is distributed as following:

```
/data
   /images/*.jpg
   /masks/*.png
   /activations/*.npz
```

I have a file that contains paths to these data files in the following format:

```
/path/to/Image_1.jpg /path/to/mask1.png /path/to/activation1.npz
/path/to/Image_2.jpg /path/to/mask2.png /path/to/activation2.npz
 .                         .                        .
```

I am creating three queues out of them, and then using readers and decoders to parse the elements in queues. Since tensorflow has defined readers like tf.read_file() and decoders such as tf.image.decode_jpeg() and tf.image.decode_png() for **jpg** and **png** formats but none for **npz** format, so I am using a python wrapper to parse the queue for activations files (third column in the file above):

```
def load_npz(npz_file):
    actv_arr = np.load(npz_file)
    activation = actv_arr['actv']
    return activation
```

Now, if I try to construct a wrapper using **tf.py_func()** around the python function above and use it to as a reader, I ran into out of range errors:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Restored model parameters from ./snapshots_curriculum_5k_data/model.ckpt-10000
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_3_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_3_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_3_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_3_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_online.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_online.py", line 241, in main
    num_steps=args.num_steps, restore_from=args.restore_from, snapshot_dir=args.snapshot_dir)
  File "/home/mac/phd/arslan-repo/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/distillation.py", line 290, in main
    _, l_val = sess.run([accum_grads_op, reduced_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_3_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]

Caused by op u'create_inputs/batch', defined at:
  File "train_online.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_online.py", line 241, in main
    num_steps=args.num_steps, restore_from=args.restore_from, snapshot_dir=args.snapshot_dir)
  File "/home/mac/phd/arslan-repo/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/distillation.py", line 94, in main
    image_batch, label_batch, activation_batch = reader.dequeue(BATCH_SIZE)
  File "/home/mac/phd/arslan-repo/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/deeplab_resnet/image_reader_distill.py", line 195, in dequeue
    num_elements)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 692, in batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 458, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1099, in _queue_dequeue_many
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_3_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
```

Following is the invocation of different readers and decoders on input queues:

```
def read_data_from_disk(input_queue):
    img_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    label_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[1])

    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_contents, channels=3)
    label = tf.image.decode_png(label_contents, channels=1)

    activation = tf.py_func(load_npz, [input_queue[2]], [tf.float32])
    activation = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(activation, [tf.shape(img)[0], tf.shape(img)[1], 21]))

    return img, label, activation
```

And ImageReader is defined as:

```
class ImageReader(object):

        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.actv_dir = actv_dir
        self.data_list = data_list
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.coord = coord

        self.image_list, self.label_list, self.actv_list = read_labeled_image_list(self.data_dir, self.actv_dir, self.data_list)
        self.images = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.image_list, dtype=tf.string)
        self.labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.label_list, dtype=tf.string)
        self.activations = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.actv_list, dtype=tf.string)
        self.queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([self.images, self.labels, self.activations],\
                                                   shuffle=input_size is not None) # not shuffling if it is val
        self.image, self.label, self.activation = read_images_from_disk(self.queue, self.input_size, random_scale, random_mirror) 

    def dequeue(self, num_elements):
        image_batch, label_batch, activation_batch = tf.train.batch([self.image, self.label, self.activation],
                                                  num_elements)
        return image_batch, label_batch, activation_batch
```

When I try to call ImageReader.dequeue(1), I ran into out of range error. I think I am not correctly using the python wrapper in this setting. Any suggestions?

Below is a sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
#! /usr/env/bin python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

DATA_DIR = './data'
DATA_LIST = './list.txt'
NUM_STEPS = 1

def load_file(file_path):
    arr = np.loadtxt(file_path)
    return arr

def get_file_list(data_dir, data_list):
    file_list = []
    f = open(data_list)
    for line in f:
        img = line.strip('\n')
        file_list.append(data_dir + img)

    return file_list

def read_files_from_disk(input_queue):
    activation = tf.py_func(load_file, [input_queue[0]], [tf.float32])
    activation = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(activation, [1, 2]))
    return activation

class File_Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, data_dir, data_list):
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.data_list = data_list
        self.file_list = get_file_list(self.data_dir, self.data_list)
        self.files = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.file_list, dtype=tf.string)
        self.queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([self.files], shuffle=True)
        self.file = read_files_from_disk(self.queue)

    def dequeue(self, num_elements):
        file_batch = tf.train.batch([self.file], num_elements)
        return file_batch

def main(data_dir=DATA_DIR, data_list=DATA_LIST, num_steps=NUM_STEPS):

    graph = tf.Graph()

    with graph.as_default():
        reader = File_Reader(data_dir, data_list)
        file_contents = reader.dequeue(1)

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

        for step in range(num_steps):
            file_content = sess.run(file_contents)
            print(file_content)

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where 'list.txt' simply consists of names of 'x' number of files and './data' contains those files. For simplicity I used 'txt' files.

Comment: Usually a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` is the result of a failure earlier in the pipeline. Were there any other exceptions in the logs?

Comment: I have edited the question with complete error log. Thanks!

Comment: This error occurs when queue has insufficient elements as shown in logs. How many files you have in the folder and what are the values of batch size and min_after_dequeue ??

Comment: For quick experimentation I am testing with 25 files, but I don't think the dearth of elements is the reason. If I just remove the activation paths from the file and only use queues for **images** and **masks**, I don't see any problems. I think it's the way I am using **tf.py_func()** that is causing the problem. I am not sure if **tf.py_func()** can be used as a reader here. 
My batch size is 1, and I am not setting min_after_dequeue.

Comment: I have added a sample code to reproduce the problem at the end of the question.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @LenarHoyt Yes, I did. IIRC, this is solved by correctly specifying the type of data to load in **load_npz()** function. 

Change following line in load_npz(): **activation = actv_arr['actv'].astype(np.float32)**